# How to have image src a variable?

Tags: php, html

I want to keep src attribute in  a variable. I am working on php and tried the following method but it doesn't display the image on html page.
Code:

```
    <?php $path="C:/horizontal.jpg"; ?>
    <image src="<?php echo $path; ?>" style="width:304px;height:228px" />
```

Comment: You have the image saved on the server disk?! You will only be able to see this on localhost! (Use `src="file:///<?php echo $path; ?>"`, but it will only works for localhost)

Comment: use `<img>` instead of `<image>`

Comment: Yeah i used img. It was a typo error. Sorry.

Comment: @Rizier123 It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use this technique:

```
<?php $path="http://" . $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];?>
<img src="<?php echo $path.'/projectName/image.jpg'; ?>" style="width:304px;height:228px" />
```

Where:

`$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]`: to get the server name, for example: www.example.com.

Also you can use `$_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"]`, in this case you can get the address IP of your server, for example: "127.0.0.1".

I hope this information helps you.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $path="localhost/projectName/";?>
<img src="<?php echo $path.'image.jpg'; ?>" style="width:304px;height:228px" />
```